# How to get all objects with certain interval of time in django?

Tags: python, django, database, orm, django-queryset

I am attempting to retrieve all objects with a time-to-live of less than 5 seconds using Django's ORM in Python. However, my current approach is not producing the expected results. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can correctly retrieve these objects?

**queryset.py**

```
def ttl_expire_list(self):
        query = self.filter(is_remove=False,ttl__range=[timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=5), timezone.now()]).order_by("-ttl")
        # query = self.filter(is_remove=False).order_by("-ttl")
        return query'
```

**models.py**

```
class Notification(models.Model):

    sender = models.CharField(_("Sender"), max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

    receiver = models.CharField(_("Receiver"), max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    message = models.TextField(_("Message"),null=True,blank=True)

    is_read = models.BooleanField(_("Read") ,default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    ttl = models.DateTimeField(_("Time to live"),null=True,blank=True) 
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Created Time"), default = timezone.now)
```

**Solution**

```
def ttl_expire_list(self):
        print("curen",timezone.now()) 
        print("imte :",timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=5))
        query = self.filter(is_remove=False,ttl__range=(timezone.now() , timezone.now()+timedelta(seconds=50))).order_by("-ttl")
        return query
```

Comment: Update question with models

Comment: @Ahtisham , Done brother

Comment: you are getting empty queryset or what?

Comment: yeah empty query

Comment: I think it should be: `ttl__range=[timezone.now(), timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)]`

Comment: Yeah fixed, Thanls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument of [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) should be start date and then end date just swap the arguments:

```
ttl__range=[timezone.now(), timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=5)]
```